# Extracting a string from a long string

Tags: sql-server

I Have a column named Config with data as below, its a long string

```
AutoFill = 1    Backgrouns = True  StoreAddress1 = '1601 River Road East'  StoreAddress2 = ''  StoreCity = 'Kitchener'  StoreProv = 'ON'  StorePostal = 'N2A 3Y4'  StorePhone = '(844) 607-6362'
```

out of which i have to extract '1601 River Road East' and put it in a different table as address line 1 , Kitchener as city in that table and ON as the Province in that table , N2A 3Y4 as postal code

the word StoreAddress1  StoreAddress2  StoreCity  is always going to be there in this long string for other rows as well

im using Microsoft SQL Server 2016
i know i have to use patindex and substring but unable to make the query

Comment: What have you tried so far? The real problem here is your storing de-normalised data in your database. Hopefully you want to do this as a one off process to fix the data? If not, then i suggest that that should *now* be the goal, so that you can fix your design and not have to deal with it like this in the future.

Comment: i have no choice but thats how the data is coming from source system and of which i have to extract these details and put it in a different table

Comment: perhaps it should be the source system you should be looking at then. Even something like XML would be vastly more preferable over the above. SQL Server's forté is not string manipulation; it's actually pretty bad at it, and it does not support REGEX. What you have above is a non-delimited mash of values.

Comment: i cannot control the source system im sorry this is how data is going to come in my table can you please help me with the query top extarct the above data from it ?

Comment: SQL Server version?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would use Visual Studio c# to change these rather than T-SQL so you could do some error checking. Something like the following.

```
var cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("your connection");
      cn.Open();
      var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select YourLongField From YourTable", cn);
      var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
      dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
      cmd.Dispose();
      for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      {        
        var split = dt.Rows[i]["YourLongField"].ToString().Split(' ');
        //Error check here before inserting a new record
        var cmdInsertNew = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Insert Into YourNiceNewTable (Address1, Address2, StoreCity, StoreProv, StorePostal, StorePhone) Values (@Address1, @Address2, @StoreCity, @StoreProv, @StorePostal, @StorePhone)", cn);
cmdInsertNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", split[2]);
        cmdInsertNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", split[3]);
        cmdInsertNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreCity", split[4]);
        cmdInsertNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreProv", split[5]);
        cmdInsertNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StorePostal", split[6]);
        cmdInsertNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StorePhone", split[7]);
        cmdInsertNew.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmdInsertNew.Dispose();
      }
      cn.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly as anything but hey... I have to use [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) here, as for the second split, the ordinal position is important. Anyway this does the "job", but leaves the single quotes around the values. That's up to you to fix afterwards.

```
WITH Pivoted AS(
    SELECT V.UndelimitedList,
           DSc.ItemNumber,
           MAX(CASE DSv.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN DSv.Item END) AS ColumnName,
           MAX(CASE DSv.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN DSv.Item END) AS ItemValue
    FROM (VALUES('AutoFill = 1    Backgrouns = True  StoreAddress1 = ''1601 River Road East''  StoreAddress2 = ''''  StoreCity = ''Kitchener''  StoreProv = ''ON''  StorePostal = ''N2A 3Y4''  StorePhone = ''(844) 607-6362'''))V(UndelimitedList)
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(REPLACE(REPLACE(V.UndelimitedList,'  ','|'),' = ','~'))) CL(DelimitedList) --Assumes no values will have a double space, and all are separated by double space
                                                                                                       --Also assumes that a Pipe (|) and Tilda (~) will never appear in your data
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(CL.DelimitedList,'|') DSc
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(DSc.Item,'~') DSv
    GROUP BY V.UndelimitedList,
             DSc.ItemNumber
    HAVING MAX(CASE DSv.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN DSv.Item END) != '')
SELECT MAX(CASE P.ColumnName WHEN 'AutoFill' THEN NULLIF(P.ItemValue,'''''') END) AS AutoFill,
       MAX(CASE P.ColumnName WHEN 'Backgrouns' THEN NULLIF(P.ItemValue,'''''') END) AS Backgrouns,
       MAX(CASE P.ColumnName WHEN 'StoreAddress1' THEN NULLIF(P.ItemValue,'''''') END) AS StoreAddress1,
       MAX(CASE P.ColumnName WHEN 'StoreAddress2' THEN NULLIF(P.ItemValue,'''''') END) AS StoreAddress2,
       MAX(CASE P.ColumnName WHEN 'StoreCity' THEN NULLIF(P.ItemValue,'''''') END) AS StoreCity,
       MAX(CASE P.ColumnName WHEN 'StoreProv' THEN NULLIF(P.ItemValue,'''''') END) AS StoreProv,
       MAX(CASE P.ColumnName WHEN 'StorePostal' THEN NULLIF(P.ItemValue,'''''') END) AS StorePostal,
       MAX(CASE P.ColumnName WHEN 'StorePhone' THEN NULLIF(P.ItemValue,'''''') END) AS StorePhone
FROM Pivoted P
GROUP BY P.UndelimitedList;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e64159d237512956b612488bb62cfc5b)